# setImage animated - NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-animation

I'm trying to `setImage:` of a `NSImageView` using animation (Mac App):

```
[[_image animator] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

But the image is just changing (without some effect). I'm trying to fade it.

Any idea how to fade two `NSImageView` in a Mac App?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5143393/1028709.

Answer (score 6):

I think this link might help you with transitions and animations with NSImageView :

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ImageTransition/ImageTransition.zip

Hope this helps